# Error graphviz Cygwin con C++

Tags: graphviz

Un saludo.

Tengo instalado *Doxywizard* para poder realizar documentación en *HTML* de los proyectos de *C++* que hago en *NetBeans*. *Utilizo, por aclararlo, Windows 10 con Cygwin*. Tengo instalado el paquete *graphviz*, pero no puedo generar gráficos.

Selecciono tal que así:

[image: Opciones seleccionadas para los gráficos (rutas de archivos sustituidas por guiones por privacidad)]

---

La salida de Cygwin es:

> ```
>     Searching for include files...
>     Searching for example files...
>     Searching for images...
>     Searching for dot files...
>     Searching for msc files...
>     Searching for dia files...
>     Searching for files to exclude
>     Searching INPUT for files to process...
>     Searching for files in directory G:------------/ejercicios3_4_5
>     Reading and parsing tag files
>     Parsing files
>     Reading G:-----------/.dep.inc...
>     Parsing file G:------------/.dep.inc...
>     Preprocessing G:----------------/main.cpp...
>     Parsing file G:-----------/main.cpp...
>     Building group list...
>     Building directory list...
>     Building namespace list...
>     Building file list...
>     Building class list...
>     Computing nesting relations for classes...
>     Associating documentation with classes...
>     Building example list...
>     Searching for enumerations...
>     Searching for documented typedefs...
>     Searching for members imported via using declarations...
>     Searching for included using directives...
>     Searching for documented variables...
>     Building interface member list...
>     Building member list...
>     Searching for friends...
>     Searching for documented defines...
>     Computing class inheritance relations...
>     Computing class usage relations...
>     Flushing cached template relations that have become invalid...
>     Computing class relations...
>     Add enum values to enums...
>     Searching for member function documentation...
>     Creating members for template instances...
>     Building page list...
>     Search for main page...
>     Computing page relations...
>     Determining the scope of groups...
>     Sorting lists...
>     Determining which enums are documented
>     Computing member relations...
>     Building full member lists recursively...
>     Adding members to member groups.
>     Computing member references...
>     Inheriting documentation...
>     Generating disk names...
>     Adding source references...
>     Adding xrefitems...
>     Sorting member lists...
>     Setting anonymous enum type...
>     Computing dependencies between directories...
>     Generating citations page...
>     Counting members...
>     Counting data structures...
>     Resolving user defined references...
>     Finding anchors and sections in the documentation...
>     Transferring function references...
>     Combining using relations...
>     Adding members to index pages...
>     Correcting members for VHDL...
>     Generating style sheet...
>     Generating search indices...
>     Generating example documentation...
>     Generating file sources...
>     Generating code for file .dep.inc...
>     Generating code for file main.cpp...
>     Generating file documentation...
>     Generating docs for file .dep.inc...
>     Generating docs for file main.cpp...
>     Generating caller graph for function leePorTeclado
>     Generating call graph for function main
>     Generating caller graph for function muestraEnPantalla
>     Generating page documentation...
>     Generating group documentation...
>     Generating class documentation...
>     Generating docs for compound Vehiculo...
>     Generating namespace index...
>     Generating graph info page...
>     Generating directory documentation...
>     Generating index page...
>     Generating page index...
>     Generating module index...
>     Generating namespace index...
>     Generating namespace member index...
>     Generating annotated compound index...
>     Generating alphabetical compound index...
>     Generating hierarchical class index...
>     Generating graphical class hierarchy...
>     Generating member index...
>     Generating file index...
>     Generating file member index...
>     Generating example index...
>     finalizing index lists...
>     writing tag file...
>     Running plantuml with JAVA...
>     Running dot...
>     Generating dot graphs using 6 parallel threads...
>     Running dot for graph 1/5
>     Running dot for graph 2/5
>     Running dot for graph 3/5
>     Running dot for graph 4/5
>     Running dot for graph 5/5
>     Patching output file 1/1
>     lookup cache used 17/65536 hits=56 misses=18
>     finished...
>     error: Problems running dot: exit code=-1, command='dot', arguments='"C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a072b56155f2619b993e05aa8afdcf63f_icgraph.dot" -Tpng -o "C:/Users/------/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a072b56155f2619b993e05aa8afdcf63f_icgraph.png"'
>     error: Problems running dot: exit code=-1, command='dot', arguments='"C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp__incl.dot" -Tpng -o "C:/Users/------/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp__incl.png"'
>     error: Problems running dot: exit code=-1, command='dot', arguments='"C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/graph_legend.dot" -Tpng -o "C:/Users/------/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/graph_legend.png"'
>     error: Problems running dot: exit code=-1, command='dot', arguments='"C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a3c04138a5bfe5d72780bb7e82a18e627_cgraph.dot" -Tpng -o "C:/Users/------/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a3c04138a5bfe5d72780bb7e82a18e627_cgraph.png"'
>     error: Problems running dot: exit code=-1, command='dot', arguments='"C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a68248c7e49c2e0ed84e6e1802d391aaf_icgraph.dot" -Tpng -o "C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a68248c7e49c2e0ed84e6e1802d391aaf_icgraph.png"'
>     error: problems opening map file C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp__incl.map for inclusion in the docs!
>     If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run, 
>     try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen.
>     error: problems opening map file C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a68248c7e49c2e0ed84e6e1802d391aaf_icgraph.map for inclusion in the docs!
>     If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run, 
>     try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen.
>     error: problems opening map file C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a3c04138a5bfe5d72780bb7e82a18e627_cgraph.map for inclusion in the docs!
>     If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run, 
>     try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen.
>     error: problems opening map file C:/Users/-----/Desktop/prueba doxygen/html/main_8cpp_a072b56155f2619b993e05aa8afdcf63f_icgraph.map for inclusion in the docs!
>     If you installed Graphviz/dot after a previous failing run, 
>     try deleting the output directory and rerun doxygen.
>     *** Doxygen has finished
> ```

---

Pero cuando abro el archivo **HTML** y busco los gráficos, no hay absolutamente nada:

[image: No hay gráfico]

He probado las versiones de **graphviz 2.40.1-2 y 2.40.1-4**, con el mismo resultado. También lo que dice en el error, de borrar la carpeta de salida y crear una nueva **(incluso la he hecho con otro nombre)**.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: No hablo español, así que usé el traductor de Google para la traducción. ¿Qué versión de doxywizard / doxygen estás usando? El doxywizard (y por lo tanto doxygen) que usa es esta la versión de Windows o una versión traducida para Cygwin? Cuando es la versión de Windows y usa graphviz / dot de Cygwin, esto no funcionará debido a las diferencias de ruta (el punto Cygwin no comprende el tipo de rutas de Windows y doxygen no sabe que usa un ejecutable Cygwin). En caso de más preguntas, utilice la versión en inglés de stackoverflow, será más fácil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo.

La ruta del bin de doxygen no se encontraba añadida al PATH de Windows, por lo que no podía encontrar el paquete. Simplemente la he añadido y el problema ha quedado solucionado.

Un saludo.